# To find the integer (Fixnum) values in ruby array

Tags: ruby, fixnum

I have an array `[1, 2, "3", "4", "1a", "abc", "a"]` with

- pure integers (`1`, `2`),
- string formatted integers (`"1"`, `"2"`),
- strings (`"a"`, `"b"`), and
- mixed string numbers (`"1a"`, `"2s"`).

From this, I need to pick up only the integers (including string formatted) `1`, `2`, `"3"`, `"4"`.

First I tried with `to_i`:

```
arr = [1, 2, "3", "4", "1a", "abc", "a"]
arr.map {|x| x.to_i}
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 0, 0]
```

but this one converts `"1a"` to `1`, which I don't expect.

Then I tried `Integer(item)`:

```
arr.map {|x| Integer(x) }  # and it turned out to be
# => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "1a"
```

Now I am out of straight conversion options here. Finally, I decided to do this way, which converts the value `to_i` and `to_s`. So `"1" == "1".to_i.to_s` is an integer, but not `"1a" == "1a".to_i.to_s` and `"a" == "a".to_i.to_s`

```
arr  = arr.map do |x|
  if (x == x.to_i.to_s)
    x.to_i
  else
    x
  end
end
```

and

```
ids, names= arr.partition { |item| item.kind_of? Fixnum }
```

Now I got the arrays of integers and strings. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: -1. You write that your array includes string formatted integers "1", "2", but they are not in your array. Also, string "b" and mixed string numbers "2s" are not found.

Comment: do you need to return it as integers or as original type. I meen do you need to get `[1,2,3,4]` or `[1,2,"3","4"]` ?

Comment: @sawa, its a typo sawa... i meant to type "3","4". what difference it makes to say string formatted numbers. its a example i wanted to convey...

Comment: If the explanations and the examples contradict, how is it possible to know your intention? If the question is difficult to understand or does not make sense, then it is not a good question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Similar solution as provided by @maerics, but a bit slimmer:

```
arr.map {|x| Integer(x) rescue nil }.compact
```

Comment: I wanted to post almost the same, but using `select` like this: `>> a.select { |i| Integer(i) rescue false } #=> [1, 2, "3", "4"]`. Anyway, since the solution is so similar, I'll let you have this one. :-)

Comment: I would say this idiom  is more pythonist than rubyist "Ask forgiveness not permission". In Ruby though, to rescue an exception might be expensive in terms of performance, see this benchmark: http://technicaldebt.com/the-cost-of-using-rubys-rescue-as-logic/

Answer (score 3):

```
class Array
  def to_i
    self.map {|x| begin; Integer(x); rescue; nil; end}.compact
  end
end

arr = [1, 2, "3", "4", "1a", "abc", "a"]
arr.to_i # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 2):

something like this:

```
a = [1,2,"3","4","1a","abc","a"]



irb(main):005:0> a.find_all { |e| e.to_s =~ /^\d+$/ }.map(&:to_i)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I would put the `to_i` inside the `find_all` block. This prevent the double iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Hey, thanks awakening my ruby. Here is my go at this problem:

```
arr=[1,2,"3","4","1a","abc","a"]
arr.map {|i| i.to_s}.select {|s| s =~ /^[0-9]+$/}.map {|i| i.to_i}
//=> [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

I noticed most of the answer so far changes the value of "3" and "4" to actual integers.

```
>> array=[1, 2, "3", "4", "1a", "abc", "a", "a13344a" , 10001, 3321]
=> [1, 2, "3", "4", "1a", "abc", "a", "a13344a", 10001, 3321]
>> array.reject{|x| x.to_s[/[^0-9]/] }
=> [1, 2, "3", "4", 10001, 3321]
```

@OP, I have not tested my solution exhaustively, but so far it seems to work (of course its done according to provided sample ), so please test thoroughly yourself.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
[1,2,"3","4","1a","abc","a"].select{|x| x.to_i.to_s == x.to_s}
# => [1, 2, "3", "4"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty simple

```
arr.select{ |b| b.to_s =~ /\d+$/ }
# or
arr.select{ |b| b.to_s[/\d+$/] }
#=> [1, 2, "3", "4"]
```